# How to stop my younger male cat from attacking my older female cat? Both are desexed

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression

I have 2 cats. I got both at the local animal shelter 5 years ago.

The female was 6 years old had her shots and spayed. She is a very sweet cat and has no problematic behavior. It took her a while to start coming out in the living room during the day and be part of the family. I guess it is because we have a few basset hounds and it took her a while to become really sure of them. Now she can’t get enough family interaction. She is solid white with blue eyes but she does hear.

Then there is our male T Monkey. He was a tiny little thing. He was a stray and no more than 3 or 4 weeks. He was too small for neutering at that time. After about 2 months he was neutered. He now has the whole house to play. I never dreamed this cat would get this big. I think he was from a litter of wild cats as he did have ear mites when he was found. He might be part Himalayan or Main coon cause he is huge with long black hair that is grayer on the under coat.

Now, the problem is, he started stalking the female cat when he became bigger than her. He wraps himself around her and bites her. She starts making noises when she sees him walking near her. It happens multiple times a day. Most of the time we are able to run him off her unless it happens at night or when only one of us are in house and the female cat is in a different room.

I am starting to worry for the female. She female is at least 11 now. I am noticing that the female is starting to look and act a little frail as his attack is relentless upon her.

He however is not a cat with absolute sweet behavior. He has more personality than any cat we have ever had. He is meaner than hell. Though he will reach out for you to pet him and be loving, watch out if he starts swishing his poofy tail. He will then wrap himself around your arm and sink his teeth and claws in. When anyone goes and gets a snack he is worse than a dog. To beg he reaches his paws for you and the snacks.

He behaves weird when he has no company. When my husband and I go away for a night he will start peeing on all the beds including the dog beds. We always leave at least 1 of 2 sons that live with us here to take care of them.

I love both cats and would not dream of giving either up. But I would like to stop him from attacking her. He even attacks her when she is in her bed in the corner up on a bar stool with a chair for her access. He jumps on the chair and attacks her.

Any advice would be helpful.